# Método burbuja para ordenar palabras en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intento implementar el método burbuja para ordenar palabras pero no me funciona.

Me ordena unas pero otras no, y necesito obtener la primera y la última de acuerdo al orden lexicográfico.

> El programa no puede usar  el método `sort()` o `sorted()`, únicamente comparación de cadenas.

Este es mi código:

```
cadena = input("Ingrese una cadena de texto: ").lower()
cadena=cadena.split()
for i in range(len(cadena)):
    for j in range(len(cadena)-1-i):
        if cadena[i]>cadena[j+1]:
            aux=cadena[i]
            cadena[i]=cadena[j+1]
            cadena[j+1]=aux\
for i in range(len(cadena)):
    print(cadena[i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea es compara cada palabra con todas las que tiene delante, el error se encuentra en tu segundo `for`, en vez de:

```
for j in range(len(cadena)-1-i):
```

debería ser:

```
for j in range(i+1, len(cadena)):
```

No necesitas de la variable auxiliar, puedes asignar en una sola sentencia. En Python puedes intercambiar el valor de dos variables con:

```
a, b = b, a
```

El código quedaría algo así:

```
cadena = input("Ingrese una cadena de texto: ").lower()
cadena=cadena.split()

for i in range(len(cadena)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(cadena)):
        if cadena[i] > cadena[j]:
            cadena[j], cadena[i] = cadena[i], cadena[j]
            
for palabra in cadena:
    print(palabra)
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

> >>> Ingrese una cadena de texto: No podemos resolver problemas pensando de la misma manera que cuando los creamos
>
> creamos
> cuando
> de
> la
> los
> manera
> misma
> no
> pensando
> podemos
> problemas
> que
> resolver

Answer (score 0):

Tienes errores en el for del bubble sort, para arreglarlo, puedes cambiarlo por ésto:

```
for palabra in range(len(cadena)-1,0,-1):
    for j in range(palabra):
        if cadena[j]>cadena[j+1]:
            aux=cadena[j]
            cadena[j]=cadena[j+1]
            cadena[j+1]=aux
```