# Convertir texto a lista de palabras y eliminar duplicados

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Estoy trabajando en un código para leer un .txt y convertir su contenido en una lista, el archivo de texto es el siguiente:

> But soft what light through yonder window breaks
> It is the east and Juliet is the sun
> Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
> Who is already sick and pale with grief

La salida deseada debe ser la siguiente:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

y el código que estoy desarrollando es así:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    esp=line.strip()
    div=line.split()
    #lst+=div
    div.sort()
    lst+=div
    lst.sort()
x=lst
print(x)
```

mi salida es esta:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'is', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Pero hay palabras repetidas, que no se como quitar, para que mi salida sea como la deseada, agradecería ayuda de algún experto.

Answer (score 4):

Te estás complicando mucho, dado que no te importa el orden de las palabras (al final las ordenas todas) usa un conjunto para eliminar los duplicados simplemente:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")

with open(fname) as file:
    lst = sorted(set(file.read().split()))
    
print(lst)
```

La salida es:

> ```
> ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks',  'east',
>  'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick',
>  'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
> ```

No necesitas iterar sobre cada fila ni aplicar `str.strip`, `str.split` se puede encargar perfectamente de separar por cualquier espacio en blanco, incluidos los saltos de líneas.

Ten en cuenta que no se eliminarán palabras duplicadas que se diferencien solo en las mayúsculas o minúsculas, por ejemplo: "What" y "what" o "IT" e "it" no se consideran igual, no se si ésto también debería eliminarse, y de ser así, con cual te quedarías de todas las posibilidades.

La existencia de símbolos de puntuación, exclamación, interrogación, etc también pueden interferir ya que `str.split` si no los va a eliminar. Tampoco se si ésto puede darse en tu texto, ni si el texto siempre será ASCII o no ni cómo te gustaría resolverlo.

Comment: Me pareció genial tu respuesta, solo que estoy haciendo un curso en Coursera, y me exigen utilizar los métodos que se ven en mi codigo, incluso me piden añadir por algun lado un .append() entonces pues no se de que modo llevarlo, no se si e sposible aplicar un metod .remove() a la lista que se creo en el codigo que subi, Muchas gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes que hacerlo de la forma aburrida, puedes hacer algo como esto:

Ordenar las palabras sueltas y luego iterar sobre ellas, pero como en el ejemplo hay palabras repetidas, puedes poner una condición para **no agregar palabras repetidas**.

Y si quieres hacer algo aun más aburrido, puedes usar el [Método Burbuja](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/110006/117155) explicado por *El domador de serpientes*.

```
ubicacion = input("ej: strings.txt")
f = open(ubicacion,'r')
frase = f.read()
f.close()
```

Luego de abrir el archivo y como el mismo posee saltos de linea(`\n`), una buena opción es, reemplazar esos saltos de linea por un espacio en blanco `' '`. Eso se puede hacer utilizando la función [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp).

```
words = frase.replace('\n',' ').split()
words.sort()  


lst = []
for word in words:
    if word not in lst:
        lst.append(word)

print(lst)
```

salida:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 
'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 
'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

pd: Ten en cuenta que si el archivo de texto se encuentra en otro directorio, tienes que pasarle el directorio completo (ej: "/home/juan/proyecto/doc.txt")

Comment: Pues, me parece una opción genial, solo que olvide añadir algo, el contenido del archivo de texto originalmente viene sin suprimir los espacios al final de cada linea, me gustaria añadir el metodo.rstrip(), solo que no estoy seguro en que parte, y tambien me gustaria ver como hacer para que específicamente por medio de un input() se solicite que ingrese el nombre del archivo a procesar por ejemplo "romeo.txt", y que se abra el archivo. Es decir segun el programa que hiciste solicitar a la variable frase con un input() y seguido una variable open(frase), No lo he conseguido de esa forma :(

Comment: acabo de modificar la respuesta, puedes intentar y decirme que tal te fue

Comment: Wow, realmente efectivo, la verdad tus aportes fueron muy importantes, me gustó muchas gracias, podrías explicarme la linea donde usaste el frase.replace? la verdad nunca he usado esa instrucción, pero muchas gracias todo funciono de maravilla, si no es mucha molestia, me gustaría entender un poco la lógica del if dentro del for. muchas gracias :')

Comment: me di cuenta que pude modificar un par de lineas de tu nuevo codigo y funciona de igual manera: la linea del .replace, simplemente deje words =frase.split() y pues el f.close() tambien lo eliminé, sin embargo lo que vi que ayudo bastante fue el f.read() , muchas gracias la verdad me ayudaste  ano estar estancado

Comment: genial entonces mucho mejor, mi duda era si en tu archivo aparecia `\n`