# Ordenar matriz por columnas

Tags: python, array, numpy, ordenamiento

Cómo puedo ordenar una matriz por columnas, de manera que la primera columna se ordene ascendentemente y la siguiente descendentemente y así sucesivamente.
Por ejemplo:
Que pase de estar así:
"[6,7,4
8,1,9
5,2,0]"
Y quede ordenada asi:
"[5,7,0
6,2,4
8,1,9]"

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo que adjuntes lo que probaste hasta ahora, modificando tu pregunta para poder colaborarte. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para más información. Saludos ;)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte. Revisa esta [respuesta a **Método burbuja para ordenar palabras en una lista**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/110006/91033) y aplica el algoritmo de la burbuja a cada columna. Cuando tengas preguntas usa el buscador antes de formularlas. **Es muy posible que alguien las haya planteado** y que les hayan brindado buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Así se voltea la lista y la guardamos en una nueva para que la podamos usar después. :) Saludos!

```
a=[6,7,4,8,1,9,5,2,0]
lista_nueva = []
for i in reversed(a):
    lista_nueva.append(i)
print(lista_nueva)
```

Comment: Hola! No es correcto responder a preguntas que no dan un código y demuestran una investigación y desarrollo previas, ya que parece que solo quieren que le resuelvan un ejercicio. Por otro lado, tu respuesta puede ser considerada de baja calidad, ya que no explicas que hace el código.

Comment: Soy nuevo en la comunidad y me he topado con un montón de respuestas así y pensé que así se contestaban, gracias por el dato. Saludos!

Comment: No te preocupes, es normal nadie nace sabiendo :). El problema es en parte de la persona que pregunta. Por otro lado en el caso de que la pregunta fuese correcta, lo que te falta sería dar un contexto a tu código para ser una buena respuesta, es decir, explicar que estás haciendo, qué hace ```reverse()```, ```append()``` y el conjunto del código. Te anímo a que leas este brevísimo tutorial [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). A mí me sirvió en su momento. Gracias por querer contribuir a la comunidad :)

Comment: Sí voy a leer el documento. Bueno es que para mí esas funciones son triviales, pero que bueno que lo mencionas. :) Gracias!